# Github actions go test cannot find package error. How can I fix this?

Tags: go, github, github-actions

I have a simple go package, but during testing within Github Actions, it is failing with this error:

`##[error]keywords.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/securisec/go-keywords/languages" in any of:`.

When I run the tests locally (I am using go mod), all the tests works fine.

For Github actions, I have tried setting `GO111MODULE` to both `on` and `off`, but still getting the same error.

The error can be observed [here](https://github.com/securisec/go-keywords/runs/774961590?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:9). My testing workflow is:

```
name: tests

on:
  - push
  - pull_request

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test package
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 3
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os:
          - ubuntu-latest
        go:
          - "1.11"
          - "1.13"
          - "1.14"
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        env:
          GOPATH: ${{ runner.workspace }}
          GO111MODULE: "on"

      - name: Go setup
        uses: actions/setup-go@v1.0.0
        with:
          go-version: ${{matrix.go}}
        env:
          GOPATH: ${{ runner.workspace }}
          GO111MODULE: "on"
      - name: Run test
        env:
          GOPATH: ${{ runner.workspace }}
          GO111MODULE: "on"
        run: |
          go get -u github.com/grokify/html-strip-tags-go
          go test ./...
      - if: failure()
        run: ls -R
```

Go mod file:

```
module github.com/securisec/go-keywords

go 1.14

require github.com/grokify/html-strip-tags-go v0.0.0-20200322061010-ea0c1cf2f119
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `github.com/securisec/go-keywords/languages` does not exist. Is your local copy an earlier copy? Can you post your `go.mod` file?

Comment: @colm.anseo I updated my post with the contents of my mod file. My local copy is in sync with master in github.

Comment: How are you running your tests locally? `go test`? Or `go test ./...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you look at the full error messages:

```
##[error]keywords.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/securisec/go-keywords/languages" in any of:
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.10.0/x64/src/github.com/securisec/go-keywords/languages (from $GOROOT)
    /home/runner/work/go-keywords/src/github.com/securisec/go-keywords/languages (from $GOPATH)
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

You will notice that you are trying to run code in Go 1.10. Go module was introduced in Go 1.11 so it will always complain that the application does not have a dependency installed.

And then if you look at your Go setup log:

```
Go setup
    GO111MODULE: on
##[warning]Unexpected input 'go-version', valid inputs are ['version']
Run actions/setup-go@v1.0.0
  with:
    go-version: 1.11
    version: 1.10
  env:
    GOPATH: /home/runner/work/go-keywords
    GO111MODULE: on
/bin/tar xzC /home/runner/work/_temp/0ce9b622-d798-400e-b86a-42d36359ad78 -f /home/runner/work/_temp/80f228cc-4b21-427f-b111-d9f296ed4990
```

You see that setup is giving a warning and installing go 1.10 for you by default.

That is because you have targeted the specific version v1.0.0 which does not understand the go-version flag. (it was added in v1.1.0 I think)

**Solution**:

Change `uses: actions/setup-go@v1.0.0` to `uses: actions/setup-go@v1` to get latest v1 version.

Or even better use v2.